# Disable button when text is entered in text box correctly and adding dialog box in c#

Tags: c#, wpf

I have been trying to figure out on disabling the text box when text is entered in the text box. I am able to do this but I have also got another problem which is, lets say you have a text box with some word i.e "Welcome". If I edit that and add more letter on to that i.e "WelcomeSSS" adding SSS then text is enabled. But when I delete "SSS" from that text box, button is still enabled and not DISABLED as the text is the same as it was before editing.

How do I make sure that the text is disabled in this situation?

And also I want to add dialog box when a user click on different button to go to different page without saving the edited content. How do i do this?

Here is my code so far:

```
private void textbox1_IsChanged(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
//SaveButton.IsEnabled = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox1.Text);
 if (TextBox1.Text.Trim().Length > 0)
{
SaveButton.IsEnabled = true;
} 

if (WpfHelpers.Confirmation(resources.QuitWithoutSaving, resources.Changes))
{

}
}
```

This is using KeyUp event handler in wpf.

Comment: Just so i am understanding this better... You want to disable a textbox if a certain phrase / word is in it?

Comment: yes basically, what i want is when text box is empty, disable the button. When its not empty then enable. I AM ABLE TO DO THIS with the above code. What I also want to do is that, if there is a text already in the text box lets say "Welcome" and when i try to edit it and make it "WelcomeSSS" it will enable but if you remove SSS from the text box and make it "Welcome" the way it was before text box should be DISABLED.

Comment: We are all putting a lot of time in answering your question. So please put some effort in asking it. E.g. Do you want to disable the text box "How do I make sure that the text is disabled in this situation?" or the button "SaveButton.IsEnabled = true"? And please seperate what you have asked at first and what you want now. This will help people understanding some of the answers below.

Comment: Did my answer help you? If so, please accept it as answer, so anyone with the same questions knows there is a working solution.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly...

```
private void textbox1_IsChanged(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{

     if (textbox1.Text == "Welcome"){
     SaveButton.IsEnabled = false;
     }
     else{
     SaveButton.IsEnabled = true;
     }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a data structure for storing the saved values. E.g. a List of strings. In the following snippet, these values are stored in the `SavedTextBoxTexts` list.

At first, the `SaveButton` gets disabled (you can do this in the XAML as well). When `SaveButton` has been clicked, the `textBox1.text` value will be stored in the list and the button gets disabled.

When `textBox1.text` is edited and `SaveButton` exists (already), the different conditions get checked.

If `textBox1.text` is already stored in `SavedTextBoxTexts` or `textBox1.text` is empty or contains only whitespace characters, `SaveButton` gets disabled. Otherwise the `SaveButton` will be enabled.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private List<string> SavedTextBoxTexts = new List<string>();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Disable button right from the beginning.
        SaveButton.IsEnabled = false;
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // The function may be called, while the window has not been created completely.
        // So we have to check, if the button can already be referenced.
        if (SaveButton != null)
        {
            // Check if textBox1 is empty or
            // textBox1.text is already in the list of saved strings.
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text) ||
                textBox1.Text.Trim().Length == 0 ||
                SavedTextBoxTexts.IndexOf(textBox1.Text.Trim()) >= 0)
            {
                // Disable Button
                SaveButton.IsEnabled = false;
            }
            else
            {
                // If textBox1.text has not been saved already
                // or is an empty string or a string of whitespaces,
                // enable the SaveButton (again).
                SaveButton.IsEnabled = true;
            }
        }
    }

    private void SaveButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Store the text in textBox1 into the SavedTextBoxTexts list.
        SavedTextBoxTexts.Add(textBox1.Text.Trim());

        // Disable the SaveButton.
        SaveButton.IsEnabled = false;
    }

    // This is executed, when the other button has been clicked.
    // The text in textBox1 will not be saved.
    private void AnotherButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (WpfHelpers.Confirmation(resources.QuitWithoutSaving, resources.Changes))
        {
            // Move to other page ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no default value. "Welcome" is just an example. In usual case, textbox is empty. When you add some text "abc" in empty textbox, save button is enabled and you save it. "abc" is saved. Then If you edit the same text box with content "abc", edit it and make it "abcddd" and remove ddd without clicking save, button is still enabled. what i want is button to be disabled if the text is in the last state i.e "abc".

Comment: Should this work for more than one saved value or just for the latest saved value?

Comment: more than one saved value.

Comment: There you go. :-)

Comment: Also for the latest saved value?

Comment: When the button is clicked, the value will be stored and the button will be disabled immediately.

Comment: Code for the second button has been added. Each button needs a dedicated function for handling the click event.

Comment: Please mark my answer as correct, if I could help you. If not, please tell me, what you are missing.

Comment: Nope it doesnt work. Doesnt allow me to use isNullOrwhitespace method. Only isnullorempty. I am using .net 4 vs 2012

Comment: I replaced isNullOrwhitespace with the code provided as replacement possibility by the MSDN documentation.

Comment: Still doesnt work. When i add content in text box and click save. Then go back and edit the same text box, and make it back to the way it was, button doesnt get disabled. It keeps enabling. Want button to get disabled when on space characyters and when nothing is changed in textbox.

Comment: You should have mentioned that! Now it will also ignore whitespaces at the end or beginning, when comparing the new value and the stored elements.

Comment: It ignores at the start when enter space. But if you edit saved content and enter space e.g welcome. Hit space after welcome will still enable the button and not disable. It should be disable not just from the start.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. Spaces at the beginning and at the end are being ignored. If I enter welcome, save it and then add a space before or after or both, the spaces will be ignored and the save button stays inactive. Please check your code and provide some clear step by step instructions on how to reproduce the problem. Maybe you could update your question to include all functional cases you want to have covered by the code.

Comment: What i want it to be like is as follows :

1)Type Welcome and save
2)Go back and Edit Welcome. Make it WelcomeSSS. Remove "SSS" using back space. Will be "Welcome", back to the way it was before. In this case, save button should be disabled, and not enable as nothing has been changed. 

Also another question to ask on top of this. I have tried to do enable disable button when you select a date from a datepicker. How can this be done? Could you provide an example of that please??

Comment: "2)Go back and Edit Welcome" To where are you going back? My Code is absolutely working fine with the example you provide. I answered your question for more than 100%. Adding requrements in the comments is not how StackOverflow is working. If you want to have more, please add another question to SE and please do that also for the datepciker stuff.

Comment: I meant firstly, type welcome and then click save. It will be saved as welcome. Then edit the same text box and make it welcomeSss, then remove SSS with back space. Do this without clicking save button. You will see the button does not get disabled. It should be disabled. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: I am sorry, but I cannot reproduce the problem on any of two different systems. Please check again, if you are really using my code 1:1 or update your question and post your complete window class.